# Why are my child background process (fork-execvp) die instatly, but work well while in the foreground?

Tags: c, linux, fork, background-process

I'm doing a homework assigment (the regular "write your own unix shell in c" assigment)

and cant make my child process run in the background properly, the are KILLED right before calling `execvp`

my intuition tells me the problem is in the signal handler or the usage of `return` in the parent process after `fork()`.

This is how I've implemented it (just for the background process) :

```
void ExeExternal(char *args[MAX], char* cmd,ExecutionMode ExeMode) {

int pID;
    switch(pID = fork()) 
{
        case -1: 
                // Add your code here (error)

                /* 
                your code
                */
                perror("fail to fork in : ExeExternal(...)\n");
                exit(-1);

        case 0 :
                // Child Process

                signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_DFL);
                signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
                signal(SIGCONT, SIG_DFL);

                usleep(20000);
                setpgrp();

                printf("trying to execvp\n");
                int run_result=execvp(args[0],args);

                if(run_result==-1)
                    {
                    perror("execvp(...) result in execvp\n");
                    exit(-1);
                    }

                break; //wont reach this part ever!

        default://the parent. pID holds child's pID

                setpgid(pID, pID); //note, this is also done in the child

                if(ExeMode==BACKGROUND) //no need to WAIT()
                {
                    return;
                }

}
}
```

and this is my signal handler (registered in my main() with `signal(SIGCHLD,handle_sigchld)`

```
void handle_sigchld(int sig) {

pid_t pid;
int status;
pid=waitpid(WAIT_ANY,&status,WUNTRACED | WNOHANG);
if (pid >0)
{

if(WIFEXITED(status)) //if terminated normally, return or exit
{
    printf("\n[%d] %d Done \n", ID, pid);   //‪[1‬] ‫‪a.out‬‬ ‫‪:‬‬ ‫‪12340‬‬ ‫‪214‬‬ ‫‪secs‬‬
}
else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) //killed with SIGINT
{
    printf("handle_sigchld:[%d] pid %d  KILLED\n",ID,pid);
}
else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) //suspended with SIGCONT
{
    printf("\n[%d] %s %d %d secs (stopped)\n", ID, value,pid,time);
}


}


}
```

I've tried to plant some prinft's and my child seems to be killed right before executing `execvp(...)`
Ive tried to print the `args[0]` and `args[1]` and it exited there, so it looks like it falls upon accessing them,

also - is that the right way to use `return` ? ive tried to replace it with `waitpid(pid,status,WNOHANG)` but it didnt helped

ANY help is greatly appreciated! even just a hint in the right direction

Comment: Use `strace` on some existing shell to see what it does.

Comment: How did you declare and initialise what is passed as 1st argument to `ExeExternal()`?

Comment: Your code could be formatted much better, btw ...

Comment: the args are passed from the main func, args[0] the program name, args[] the arguments array. the regular convention. this works when I am running a foreground process i.e put waitpid in the parent